# Python import module

Tags: python, module

I am a beginner in python and suppose this is a simple question.

I'm trying to import a module downloaded from the web and I've installed it properly. Normally modules should be available after they are imported. But for this module after I import it --`import hddm`, it also requires more input -- `In:`. What does `In` mean in this context?

I've checked the tutorial about the module, but that doesn't help.

Comment: Could you please post what output you get from the console after calling `import hddm`?

Comment: It looks like hddm has a dependency on a module that changes the REPL prompt. That is, rather than seeing `>>>` you now see `In:` (this is the prompt for `ipython`). Basically, python is ready to use and asking you for input eg. `print(1 + 2)`.